# fb share site shows blank image

Tags: facebook

I am using Jetpack and even though when I see page source of my front page I can see the section of

```
<!-- Jetpack Open Graph Tags -->
<meta property="og:image" content="http://pitupi.de/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/DSC6291bearbeitetslider_smaller.jpg" />
```

no photo shows up when sharing on facebook

Using the Debugger from facebook found here 
`og:image` is pulled out as blank image.

I have read several posts mentioning the issue and also a function to be added on the functions.php but it did not work for me.
Please help, any tips appreciated.